# Dynamically set table name from string to symbol like "table": {status: 0}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, dynamic, symbols

I want to dynamically set table name as a symbol in where clause for Activerecord.

It works well with using fat allow.

```
def find
    @users.includes(type(@params[:filter])).where(:"#{@review}" =>  { status: 10 })
end

private

def type(type)
    case type
    when 'article_review'
      @review = Review.table_name # "reviews"
      :reviews # set as incluedes(:reviews)
    when other_name
      other definition
    end
end
```

but I dont want to use fat allow and I want def find like this below

```
def find
   @users.includes(type(@params[:filter])).where("#{@review}": { status: 10 })
end
```

How can I do this?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Read first [`sql injection`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection)

Comment: I don't put params directly into methods. I sanitized them through the private method at def type

Answer (score 0):

You should use `to_sym` method to convert string into symbol.

Here is my output

```
2.1.5 :007 > a = "table"
 => "table" 
2.1.5 :008 > a.to_sym
 => :table
```

for more check here http://apidock.com/ruby/String/to_sym

Try this

```
@users.joins(type(@params[:filter])).where("#{@review}.status = 10")
```

Comment: I already tried it and it doesn't work with the error below.

syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}'
      { "reviews".to_sym { status: 10 } }

Comment: yes! Exactly! I want to filter them by where condition with included teble

Comment: Thanks for your answer!!